# Run Module Update error when updating Freeform (free) from 3.1.2 to 4.2.2

Tags: solspace-freeform, php-errors, update, updating

I'm trying to update Freeform (free version) from 3.1.2 to 4.2.2

***NOTE:*** I recently updated EE from v2.5.3 to v2.9.3

After I upload the new folders to the system and themes directories, and go to:

*Admin > Modules > **Run Module Updates***

I get the following error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'settings' in 'field list'
>
> UPDATE `exp_freeform_fieldtypes` SET `settings` = '[]'
>
> Filename: third_party/freeform/models/freeform_model.php
>
> Line Number: 471

I've tried to revert back, by replacing the folders in system and themes with the old version and, then I get this error in:

*Admin > Modules > **Freeform**:*

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Creating default object from empty value
>
> Filename: addon_builder/addon_builder.php
>
> Line Number: 1333
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Cp::set_variable() in
>   /admin/expressionengine/third_party/freeform/addon_builder/addon_builder.php
>   on line 1389

And now I'm stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooo yeah you shouldn't have tried to revert. I ran into this issue upgrading a huge site; they literally just have a bug in the updater if I remember correctly. You just need to get the settings for the column from a previous backup, and make sure you create that column manually with the correct settings. Sorry, wish I could be more specific, but I don't have time to recreate the issue right now to give you a better answer.

But I would recommend reupdating FreeForm and then just manually creating that column.

Comment: I ended up wiping the old version and doing a clean install of 4.2.2 - they didn't have many entries and weren't too concerned with keeping them in the admin, so that was a quick/easy way to go...  Thanks for the insight!

Comment: I'm glad you worked it out!